# Asus Zenpad S 8.0 vs Galaxy Tab S2 8.0 - Travel

Tags: android, tablet

I am in the market for an android tablet, I am mostly rounded down to an 8" model (though not 100% on this) . Looking at the Asus Zenpad s 8.0 or the Galaxy S2 8.0

My primary uses will be watching movies on the plane (I travel a lot) and using the Hema Explorer GPS tracking and navigation app for offroad driving. ANd some games, but not a key purpose.

My movies/tv will be a mix of Google Play store rentals, Netflix, stan and the Virgin Entertainment system.

My current phone is a Xperia Z3 compact, I like having a compact phone so don't want to upgrade. I have run the Hema app on my phone, it lagged a bit when recording tracks. So performance of the tablet is pretty important to me. My main concerns with above tablets is the aspect ratio and watching movies.

So ;

What would you recommend that is on the current market (US or AU)? 
In real world how much screen do i actually lose with the 4:3 aspect ratio watching movies
I really don't want to spend over $500, buying from the US should make this possible.

I have considered iPad as well, but i am in the Android ecosystem so unless there is some great reason why it would suit me better i just don't see the point.